# Casting to a Subclass

Tags: java, c#

When I do this:

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
```

where Dog is a subclass of Animal, is the fact that the object is actually a Dog type ever exposed to the system, or is it lost forever? This question pertains to Java and C# because I assume they are similar, but for clarity let's focus on C#.

Based on my knowledge, I'd assume that the object would forever be considered an Animal object. The properties and methods of Dog would be assigned to the object instance but we would never know it was instantiated from a Dog class.

Comment: if you do `dogDog = (Dog)dog;` you will get all properties/methods of `Dog`, so you will get access to them

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. You can do `Dog realDog = (Dog) dog;` Also `if ( dog is Dog )` should return true, AFAIK. (<== C#, but equivalents for Java)

Comment: You can just cast the object

Comment: Another question - do we need to care about what is concrete type of `Animal`? If you care about - then you shouldn't use inheritance in this case

Comment: Please stick with a single language choice, they may be similar, but may be completely different.

Comment: In C# it is an instance of Dog, you've just sort of down casted it to an animal in terms the way you're using it in your code. It is still considered a Dog in terms of memory because that is what you've allocated when you instantiate that class

Comment: @Fabio While this ("do we need to care") is true, if it were as OP assumes then for example in a Visitor Pattern, you'd have troubles, too.

Comment: Also, you should note that attempting to call Dog specific methods on dog would not work. Only methods that have been declared in the Animal class can be called. To call a Dog specific method, you would need to cast the Animal reference to Dog i.e. Dog d = (Dog) dog;

Comment: "Based on my knowledge" - where did you get that knowledge?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexghi/2009/05/19/compile-time-type-vs-runtime-type-of-a-variable/

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can check whether dog is instance of Dog using instanceof:

```
if (dog instanceof Dog) ...
```

Comment: And C# provides `Dog realDog = dog as Dog` which will result in `realDog` being `null` if it's not of that class.

Comment: @FakeCaleb Its nothing wrong with 'is' its just to find out if something is subclass of. When you would cast to subclass next you can use as instead.

Comment: @TomSchardt my point being, the original answer doesn't do that but only sees if the object IS a `Dog`. Just curious why daniu didn't keep inline with that

Comment: @FakeCaleb Nothing wrong as such, but `as` is somewhat cleaner to read: `Dog dog = animal as Dog; if (dog != null) // work with dog` vs `if (animal instanceof Dog) { Dog dog = (Dog) animal; // work with dog`, which still requires the explicit cast.

Comment: @daniu Just curious, thought there may have been a reason

Comment: @FakeCaleb No difference, just syntactical sugar: ´as´ is implemented as ´is´ internally

Answer (score 1):

in C# you can check wheter dog is instance of Dog using is:

```
if(dog is Dog) ...
```

or using as:

```
var dog = animal as Dog;
if( dog != null )
    dog.Bark();
```

Comment: or shorter `if( animal is Dog dog ) dog.Bark();`

Comment: @Fildor nice and even better!

Answer (score 0):

You will get access to `Dog`'s proerties/methods by casting instance of `Animal` to `Dog`

```
Animal dog = new Dog();

// then somewhere
var dogDog = (Dog)dog;
```

In case you not sure is it `Dog` or not - use "soft" casting

```
var mayBeDog = animal as Dog;
if (maybeDog != null)
{
    // is Dog
}
else
{
    // wasn't Dog
}
```

Another question - do we need to care about what is concrete type of Animal? 
If you care about - then you shouldn't use inheritance in this case

Assume you have a method which takes `Animal` as parameter, that mean that you should be able pass any derived class of `Animal` and your method will work in expected manner.

Comment: Of course this will throw an exception if `dog` is not a `Dog`.

Comment: to avoid said exception: `Dog dogDog = dog as Dog;` (will be `null` if not a Dog)

Comment: I think question wasn't about how to cast object, but generally is it possible to access specific properties of derived class.

Comment: @Fabio Sorry 'bout that. I've been carried away.